# Есть возможность сделать редирект с добавлением параметров в тело запроса?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, http, asp.net-core

К примеру, мне пользователь делает запрос POST с телом `{"a":"1"}`.
Могу ли я приняв его добавить в тело "b" - `{"a": "1", "b": 354}` вернуть со статуcом 3xx, и пользователь автоматически делает запрос POST с дополненным телом на сервис, на который я его перенаправлю?
Какой 3xx лучше использовать для этого?

Comment: Вообще не понятно, что хотите, что делаете, и вообще для чего это нужно, можно чуть подробнее (понятнее) описать вашу проблему?

Comment: Хочу понять это(изменение тела запроса при редиеркте, так что бы пользователь обратился на перенаправляемый сервис с новым телом) возможно или нет? Что я делаю и зачем мне это - не важно.

Comment: Зачем вы это делаете, это конечно ваше дело, но вот как. это уже непосредственно представляет интерес, так как на основе такой информации можно дать ответ. Вопрос, а к апи сервера вы имеете отношение? И какое отношение вы имеете к клиенту?

Comment: Клиент и сервер(куда клиент первоначально делал запрос) - мои, а сервис куда делаю редирект - нет

Comment: Нет. вы не только не можете сделать такое, а даже заставить клиента протащить изначальный POST через редирект. Клиент все равно ваш - пусть он получает "b" с вашего сервиса и урл куда сделать POST запрос...ну и делает его